# Get previously printed line from console output in C

Tags: c, console-application

I'm making a very simple console text editor. In order to move the cursor to the end of the previous line when I backspace at the beginning of a line, I need to read an already printed line from the console, then get its length. How would I go about making this work?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this using `scanf()` and `printf()`; the program would need to keep track of what it prints. However, it is also impossible to edit previously printed screen lines using only the standard I/O functions - in order to do that, you'd need to use e.g. [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Answer (score -1):

Store every element you print in the editor in an char array, because you may have to go back all way up to start or in the middle, not only one line up.